# Regular Expressions looping issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, regex

I am creating a javascript(Node.js) looping function that is supposed to iterate through an array of strings, then return true or false when tested against a regular expression. If FALSE, return the value immediately (breaking the loop). However, the second value in the array still returns false, although it is valid.

The calling function passes these values:

```
var valuesArray = ["ABCXYZ", "ABCXYZ1"];
var regexValue = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
var regex = new RegExp(regexValue);

function validateArrayValues(valuesArray, regex) {
    var regexResult, item;
    for (let counter = 0; counter < valuesArray.length; counter++) {
        item = valuesArray[counter];
        regexResult = regex.test(item);
        if (!regexResult) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: [It works just fine for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/nuj1f9bq/)

Comment: Thanks Mike, I clipped out a bunch of the other code that surrounds it to keep it generic. It could be that I am calling this in a chain of Promises, in a AWS Lambda function. I will mark it as answered and move on.

Comment: Is there any reason why you write your code that complicated? I'd prefer simply `valuesArray.every(regex.test);`, which seems almost as short as the function name. If you desperately need a function, how about `const validateArrayValues = (ar => ar.every(regex.test));`?

Comment: There are many reasons, as there is additional steps and logic that follows. Thank you for your contribution philag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work correctly, anything else you removed to keep the example simple?

```js
var valuesArray = ["ABCXYZ", "ABCXYZ1"];
var regexValue = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
var regex = new RegExp(regexValue);

function validateArrayValues(valuesArray, regex) {
    var regexResult, item;
    for (let counter = 0; counter < valuesArray.length; counter++) {
        item = valuesArray[counter];
        regexResult = regex.test(item);
        if (!regexResult) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(validateArrayValues(valuesArray, regex));
```